# Core Data error with Xcode 9

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

I'm working on updating an existing app.  I'm trying to start with a Master / Detail template with Xcode 9.

Create New - Master Detail Template
Name - "This & That" (with a space before the & and after the &)

When I try to build it (I've added nothing else.. just the steps I've listed), I get an error and it won't build.

Error - This___That.xcdatamodeld: The operation couldn’t be completed. (IDEFoundation.IDETemplateParseError error 1.)

I'm guessing it is either a bug, or something is wrong with my Xcode somehow.  Any time I've done a filename with the " & ", it gives this error when trying to build, and won't go any further.  Other projects that do no have " & " in the file name work fine.

Anyone else have the problem, or am I the only one? (Can anyone try this to see if it does give them the error?)

Answer (score 0):

XCode just doesn't like that file name. Creating a new project with that name, I get this error:

[image]

> Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code
>   generation: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "No current
>   version for model at path /Users/#/Documents/#/#/#/#/This &
>   that.xcdatamodeld:"
>   UserInfo={NSFilePath=/Users/#/Documents/#/#/#/#/This &
>   that.xcdatamodeld, NSLocalizedDescription=No current version for model
>   at path /Users/#/Documents/#/#/#/#/This & that.xcdatamodeld:}

If I remove the spaces, it will build successfully.

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  Since I already have a project with the name, it must be a bug.  I'll file it.